# ASP with Crystal Report 9 hangs on .NET framework 3.5

Tags: asp.net, iis, .net-3.5, crystal-reports, windows-server-2003

We have an ASP (not ASP.NET) application running on Windows 2003 server. One of the functions of the application is to generate reports using Crystal Report 9.

It has been working without any problem with .NET Framework 2.0 and now it is required to install .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 on the server but after we installed the 3.5 SP1, every time we run the application the Crystal report is not generated and the web page hangs so we have to recycle the application pool in IIS to get the application back going.

Does anyone have any idea/solution to this problem? Any help will be greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

If the app requires .NET 2.0 and you installed a latter version of .NET, the version of .NET registered with IIS might have changed.  I've had this happen a few times with my MSSQL 2000 Report Services and .NET 1.1.  When this happens, I have to re-register the correct  version of .NET with IIS.

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\<.NET Version>\aspnet_regiis -i
```

This will force that specific version of .NET to re-register itself with IIS.

Comment: .NET Framework 3.5 uses the same CLR as .NET 3.0 and 2.0. The only difference is that service packs are installed. In the case of .NET 3.5 SP1, .NET 2.0 service pack 2 is installed.